# Can't figure out how to create an array within Foreach loop to spit out email list using Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

MODEL:

```
public function get_app(){
        $this->db->select('email');
        $this->db->from('app');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();        

    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
                $this->load->model('po_model');
                $this->po_model->po_insert($data);
                $emails = $this->po_model->get_app();


                foreach($emails as $email){

                $app = array('app_email'=> $email->email);
                }


                //SEND NOTIFICATION
                $to = $app['app_email'];
```

I need to create a list of emails retrieved from the db, to add to the mail function to send out notifications, but I'm having a hard time containing that list in an array using a foreach loop to gather email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is little modification for your code

```
$this->load->model('po_model');
$this->po_model->po_insert($data);
$emails = $this->po_model->get_app();

$app= array();
foreach($emails as $email){
  $app[] =  $email->email;
}
//SEND NOTIFICATION
$to = implode(',',$app);
```

above code add all email in array, when you want to send implode them with code and send to all. if you want to send everybody a single email just put your mail code in loop and send mail.

Comment: Awesome! I will try this

Comment: Implemented this, works like a charm, thanks umefarooq!

Comment: ;) happy to know that my solution help you.